# C++-module import chain results in strange compiler errors

Tags: c++, c++20, clang++, c++-modules

When compiling c++-20 modules with clang. I get strange compilation errors when importing a file that imports another file that imports a third file like so:

```cpp
// a.cppm
#include <string>

export module a;

export std::string getStuffA() {
  return "a";
}
```

```cpp
// b.cppm
#include <string>

import a;

export module b;

export std::string getStuffB() {
  return "b" + getStuffA();
}
```

```cpp
// c.cpp
#include <string>

import b;

int main() {
  std::cout << getStuffB() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The compiler outputs:

```
In file included from ./src/c.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/iostream:39:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/ostream:38:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/ios:44:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/bits/basic_ios.h:37:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/bits/locale_facets.h:2569:5: error: inline declaration of 'isspace' follows non-inline definition
```

And it lists some more functions that seems to have both inline and non-inline definiton, like isprint, iscntrl, isupper.

Is there any way to get around these errors.

Note: Removing `std::string` and `#include <string>` removes the compilation errors, so I think that the errors comes from `<string>`

Comment: Module support looks like it needs gcc 11 see https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html

Comment: Ok, so you need the gcc 11 headers?

Comment: Am not sure; compiler support (just language support) is not the same as Standard Library support - you are going to need to check both.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66411157/import-std-lib-as-modules-with-clang  _"...The C++20 standard does not include module definitions for the C++ standard library..."_

Comment: @RichardCritten No I know, but you must be able to use the standard library somhow.

Comment: @S.M. I will try -stdlib=c++ and come back with an answer

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped, it must be `-stdlib=libc++`

Comment: @S.M. Yes no prop found it with some googling. That solves the problem. Thanks! I guess that if you write it as a regular answer i would accept that :)

Comment: @S.M. Fixed. Tried to throw together a minimal viable example in the editor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already said, modules are supported in gcc 11, and you are trying to use clang with gcc 10 standard C++ library.

With using the proper C++ standard library, preprocessor include directives such as `#include <string>` will be automatically mapped to `import <string>;`. With using the standard C++ library for gcc 10, that does not support modules, you will get errors such as you have got.

If you use clang, that supports modules, and it seems you are using such modern clang, otherwise you would get another errors on the import directive, you should use the clang C++ standard library: `-stdlib=libc++`.