# How to compile/use header units in MSVC from command-line?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, command-line, module, c++20

For example I have following toy files:

**mod.hpp**

```
#include <iostream>
```

**use.cpp**

```
import "mod.hpp";

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
}
```

But if you compile it like `cl use.cpp /std:c++latest` then I get error

```
error C7612: could not find header unit for 'mod.hpp'
```

How do I create/use header units in MSVC?

**NOTE**: I'm making cross-platform/cross-compiler projects right now. It means that I want same sources to be able to compile in MSVC/CLang/GCC on both Windows and Linux. For me there is no point to make MSVC-specific extensions .ixx/.cppm, thats why I used .hpp/.cpp in my case. More then that I'm not making .vcxproj/.sln files at all, I'm only considered about low-level command line invocation for compiling in MSVC.

This question was made by me just to share my answer with ready-made solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create precompiled header unit issue next command:

```
cl /EHsc /std:c++latest /exportHeader mod.hpp
```

this command creates `mod.hpp.ifc` file, which is a precompiled header unit module. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/module-exportheader?view=msvc-160) is documentation about `/exportHeader` flag.

Then to use header unit issue command:

```
cl /EHsc /std:c++latest use.cpp /headerUnit mod.hpp=mod.hpp.ifc
```

documentation about `/headerUnit` is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/headerunit?view=msvc-160). `/headerUnit` accepts param `header-filename=ifc-filename`. After command above final program compiles and outputs:

```
Hello, World!
```

This way you can precompile any header, including standard ones like `import <iostream>;`.

For commands above I used following files:

**mod.hpp**

```
#include <iostream>
```

**use.cpp**

```
import "mod.hpp";

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Module file definitions are not supposed to use `.hpp` and `.cpp` suffixes in Visual Studio (and likely other build systems). They use the `.ixx` and `.cppm` suffixes in VS. You're basically [avoiding all of the special things VS does to help build module files](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/standard-c20-modules-support-with-msvc-in-visual-studio-2019-version-16-8/#include-translation).

Comment: @NicolBolas You know why I used .hpp/.cpp? Because I'm making cross-platform/cross-compiler projects right now, I can make this note in my question for clarity. It means that I want same sources to be able to compile in CLang/GCC too and both on Win and Linux. It means there is no point to make MSVC-specific extension .ixx/.cppm. More then that I'm not makes vcxproj/sln files at all right now, I'm only considered about low-level command line invocation for compiling in MSVC, and this low-level invocation like above doesn't need any special extensions to be compilable.